# http status 404 error, i

Tags: java, html, servlets, jakarta-ee

Same code works in other PC, and my connection are same and imported all required files

I've tried all solutions there in YouTube but nothing solved my error

In **Register.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Registration Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <cl>
            <h1 align="center">Registration Form</h1>
            <form action="servlet/ServletRegister" method="post">
                <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="FirstName" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="LastName" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>DOB:</td>
                        <td><input type="date" name ="DateOfBirth" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Mobile.No:</td>
                        <td><input type="tel" name="MobileNo" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>E-Mail:</td>
                        <td><input type="email" name="Email" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Create Password:</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="Password" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Address:</td>
                        <td><textarea name="Address"></textarea><br></td>
                    </tr>
                </cl>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value= "Save Data"> &nbsp
<input type="reset" value="clear"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <br><br>
            <div align="center"> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Already Registered..? &nbsp <a href="LoginPage.html">Click Here.</div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in **ServletRegister.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/ServletRegister")
public class ServletRegister extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ServletRegister() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
        String fn= request.getParameter("FirstName");
        String ln= request.getParameter("LastName");
        String dob= request.getParameter("DateOfBirth");
        String mbno= request.getParameter("MobileNo");
        String mail= request.getParameter("Email");
        String pwd= request.getParameter("Password");
        String addr= request.getParameter("Address");


        try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vikas","root","rass");  
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into reg values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, fn);
            ps.setString(2, ln);
            ps.setString(3, dob);
            ps.setString(4, mbno);
            ps.setString(5, mail);
            ps.setString(6, pwd);
            ps.setString(7, addr);

            int i= ps.executeUpdate();

            if(i>0)
            {
                //response.sendRedirect("Images/images.jpg");
                out.println("Registered Successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                out.println("Not Registered");
            }

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        out.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is mapped onto `servlet/ServletRegister`

```
<form action="servlet/ServletRegister" method="post">
```

But your servlet has a different mapping:

```
@WebServlet("/ServletRegister")
```

You need to change your form mapping to match the servlet mapping:

```
<form action="ServletRegister" method="post">
```